# C - Pipe using printf and scanf.. pausing

Tags: c, pipe, stdout, stdin

I’m new to C and I’m trying to figure out how to send the output of one program to another for processing.… or PIPE it.

Eg.  ./foo | ./boo

foo - reads data from an external source every 100ms and writes it to stdout.

boo - reads data from stdin, does some simple calculations and writes it to stdout,

(I don't have access to foo, but it writes a float value every 100ms on a new line.)

I have it working, however after every couple of hundred entries… there is a 2 second pause...

so it spits out about 200 lines, 2 second pause, 200 lines, 2 second pause. etc..

Is there a buffer I need to be aware off?

Here is the code for boo;

```
#include <stdio.h>
float input;
float value;

while (1)
    {
    input = scanf("%f", &value);

    {do stuff here}

    printf("result %f \n ", input);
    fflush(stdout);

    }
    return  0;
}
```

**EDIT**
I found the issue, foo had a loop for the 100ms delay.  when piping this into boo it was somehow getting grouped together.  Removing this loop fixed the issue

Comment: I notice there's no newline in your `printf`. If that's the case, you should call `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf`.

Comment: Thanks David, I have updated the code with the newline char & fflush and I am still getting the same results.

Comment: You dont have to flush stdout if you print a `\n`

Comment: @Mwilliams03: Then maybe it's the input that's pausing?

Comment: I just ran foo, and it writes continuously to stdout without any pausing.

Comment: I counted the exact number of lines... and it seems to be every 146 lines, it pauses.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT I found the issue, foo had a loop for the 100ms delay. when piping this into boo it was somehow getting grouped together. Removing this loop fixed the issue

I removed this loop and it fixed the issue;

```
int millis()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (tv.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv.tv_usec)/1000;
}
start = millis()
while(millis() - start < 20)
 {
  usleep(1000);
 }
```